# angularJS read response cookie parameter empty

Tags: angularjs, cookies

If I made a request on my server with $http I get the following response:

```
Request URL:http://www.test.tst/login
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=349AD3AC797C6AB28121ADA1766FF4A2
Host:www.test.tst
```

i implemented it that way:

```
$scope.checkToken = function () {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://www.test.tst/login', params: {'action.code': 'LINK', 'linkparameter': $rootScope.token}}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log($cookieStore.get('JSESSIONID'));
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $location.path("/login");
                });
        }
```

can anybody tell me, why $cookieStore.get('JSESSIONID') is always undefined?

the cookie domain is the same as the domain my request is coming from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularJS read response cookie empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566874/angularjs-read-response-cookie-empty)

Comment: The duplicate mentioned by @Florian has been removed by author.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [$cookie service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookies), and not the $cookieStore
$cookie provides access to the browser cookies; while $cookieStore allows you to store and retrieve values.

It means to access the cookies set by the server, you will use $cookie.$cookieStore.get() will allow you to access values you stored in your application, using $cookieStore.set()
Just replace $cookieStore with $cookie in your code.